# How to efficiently initial data in Django forms.Form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For example I have a Article model for blog articles so it's easy to add articles to the database.

But when I need to edit them, in form if I create a form class by `form.ModelForm`, I can pass `instace=artcile` to the form and that's it.

But if I create a form class by `form.Forms` I have to declare a form instance and pass fields to the form one by one.

Something like this

```
form = ArticleForm({
    'title': article.title,
    'body': article.body,
    'pub_date': article.pub_date
    'status': article.status,
    'author': article.author,
    'comments': article.comments.count(),
    'blah': article.blahblah,
    'againBlah': article.againBlah,
    .....
})
```

It's ugly, isn't?
Is there any way to do this shorter, without using `form.ModelForm`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do with your form. What do you mean by: "if i create form class by form.ModelForm, i can pass instace=artcile to form and that's it." What are you trying to do where using a model form wouldn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `model_to_dict` and `fields_for_model` utils from `django.forms.models`:

```
# assuming article is an instance of your Article model:
from django.forms import Form
from django.forms.models import fields_for_model, model_to_dict

form = Form(model_to_dict(article))
form.fields.update(fields_for_model(article))
```

If you have an m2m relation, you can create a formset for it:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict, fields_for_model
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

# assuming your related model is called 'Tag'
class TagForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.update(fields_for_model(Tag))


TagFormSet = formset_factory(TagForm)
formset = TagFormSet(initial=[model_to_dict(tag) for tag in article.tags.all()])
```

Then you can iterate through the formset to access the forms created for the related models:

```
for form in formset.forms:
    print form
```

Comment: what about case in model_to_dict?, i change it with article, but when form is related tag for article have problem, and showing like this-> "tag", "tag", "tag3" , "article", and when i update article it's going awesome like this -> """"tag"""", ""tag""", "'''"""tag3""""" ????

Comment: I'm no sure I understand what you're describing--are you getting an error?

Comment: i don't getting any error, but it's not suitable for my Article model with ManyToMany relation tag!

Comment: i think it's better to creating a function in form class to doing this, aha?

Comment: @lettertwo Instead of adding another answer, just edit this answer to include the information about the formset, since that answer in itself does not answer the original question.

Comment: @Alir3z4 I elaborated a bit on the answer--it may help you with the m2m relation.